# Dynomitedb and ruby gem 'redis'

Tags: ruby, redis, netflix

We are using Ruby gem to 'Redis' to connect to dynomite from our ruby application. If the redis in that node is not available or getting killed, the requests are not getting forwarded to nodes or replicas in other racks.

Is there any configuration we have to set to forward requests to other nodes when redis in that machine is not available ?

Is it is the feature not available in dynomite ?

Do I have to use some way or some other gem instead of redis to connect to dynomite ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm just researching this myself; I've discovered Dynomite doesn't provide any failover or anything like that. However, their own [Dyno](https://github.com/Netflix/dyno) java client does provide this functionality.

> Any client that can talk to Memcached or Redis can talk to Dynomite -
>   no change needed. However, there will be a few things missing,
>   including failover strategy, request throttling, connection pooling,
>   etc., unless our Dyno client is used (more details to in the Client
>   Architecture section).

Source: http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/introducing-dynomite.html